# image picker popover

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

```
AGImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[AGImagePickerController alloc] initWithFailureBlock:^(NSError *error) {

    if (error == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"User has cancelled.");
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    } else
    {     
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

        // Wait for the view controller to show first and hide it after that
        double delayInSeconds = 0.5;
        dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        });
    }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault animated:YES];

} andSuccessBlock:^(NSArray *info) {
    NSLog(@"Info: %@", info);
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault animated:YES];
}];

popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePickerController];
[popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 400.0, 400.0) 
                         inView:self.view.window
       permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny 
                       animated:YES];
```

was able to present it, but, even I change the size its still the same, and when I pressed the `DONE` button, it removes my View controller not the imagepicker. Help please. I present it in a popover cause I think that, thats's why its slow it because imagepicker should be present with popover for iPad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resize set it this way:

```
[popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(1024, 500)];
```

then in your `andSuccessBlock` and other part you used:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

should be

```
[popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
```

That's why `ViewController` is being dismissed or removed from the view, because it is being dismissed the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

Are you implementing the AGImagePickerController delegates?

```
- (void)agImagePickerController:(AGImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSArray *)info;
```

There you can dismiss your `UIPopoverController`.

Comment: I need to change the frame of the popover

Comment: I guess you mean the content frame? `setPopoverContentSize:animated:` or you can change the property `popoverController.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width,height)`  [UIPopoverController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html)